# Read words with spaces as one word

Tags: bash, read

I'm attempting to read words with spaces as one words and multiple spaces as a second word.  Is there an easy way to do this:

```
UNLIMITED TABLESPACE                     TRUSH
SELECT ANY DICTIONARY                    KENNYGO
```

Based on the example `Unlimited Tablespace` would be one word and `Trush` the second. `Select any dictionary` one word and `Kennygo` the second.

I'm attempting to do this with a `read` command:

```
while IFS="  " read -r privilege name; do
    echo "$privilege" break "$name"
done < sysprivs.exp
```

The current result set is:

```
UNLIMITED break TABLESPACE                     TRUSH
SELECT break ANY DICTIONARY                    KENNYGO
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter your input first, turning runs of multiple spaces
into newlines before having `read` go through it:

```
(<sysprivs.exp sed 's/\ \ \+/\n/g' | while read word; do echo "Word: \`$word'"; done)
```

Output:

```
Word: `UNLIMITED TABLESPACE'
Word: `TRUSH'
Word: `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY'
Word: `KENNYGO'
```